# Python program for inputting word amount requirement , testing , storing , printing words and letters in reverse

Tags: python

Python program that allows user to enter atleast 5 words , test it , store the words  as seperate items in a list , print words in reverse order , words must be in one line with spacing , lastly print the words and letter in reverse order

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Can you show some example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the welcome [tour] and go over the [help]. Pay extra attention to the section about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the user to input the 5 words in a single line separated by spaces and store them into a list, you could use something like this

```
inputList = input().split()
```

For reversing the order of the words as well as reverse the words themselves, you could use

```
inputList = [word[::-1] for word in inputList[::-1]]
```

The code above will reverse the words as well as the order of the words.

So for an input like

> one two three four five

The output would be

> ['evif', 'ruof', 'eerht', 'owt', 'eno']